# How setup my apache tomcat(os-windows XP) to allow BOSH servlet for Xmpp chat?

Tags: tomcat, xmpp, openfire

Am developing java jquery mobile app for chat using XMMP server(openfire) 
and  xmpp4js at client side.

while running the app am getting ERROR:**Access control allow origin**

at this code

```
 this.con = new Xmpp4Js.Connection({
            transport: {
                clazz: Xmpp4Js.Transport.BOSH,
                endpoint: " http://localhost:7070/http-bind" 
            },
```

and in console   :There was an error(fatal=true): The error is not one of those defined herein; the connection manager SHOULD include application-specific information in the content of the wrapper.

while i search, some blog gives information to setup my Apache tomcat to allow Bidirectional-streams Over Synchronous HTTP (BOSH) but that info for ubuntu.
can any give me idea to do my task..

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

Not very sure if you are still looking for an answer or not but putting it here for those who might be digging for one.
The problem here is the fact that cross domain calls are blocked by you javascript engine (which in this case is your browser). Your calls could be sent to the originating domain only. To solve the problem you have to send a call to the existing domain with a particular path, and let the webserver forward this path to your BOSH XMPP server. In order to do this you have to define a proxy under your Apache. There is a comprehensive tutorial [here](http://frishit.com/2010/06/setting-up-xmpp-bosh-server/).